# Check Python Object Attribute class

Tags: python, class, validation, attributes

I have a class Quad for checking if an instance is a few different forms of Quadrilaterals where the parameters for it are (sideAB,sideDA,angleA). Angle a is assumed to be in degrees.

How would I be able to perform a check to validate the object if the attributes are numeric? I know I could perform exceptions outside the class but is this the way I should best handle validation within the class?

Sorry if this seems a bit elementary, I'm relatively new to python. And I am brand new to this site so if you have any suggestions on more appropriate post content let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something explicit like:

```
class Quad(object):

    def __init__(sideAB, sideDA, angle):
        if not isinstance(sideAB, (int, float)):
            raise ValueError("All arguments must be numeric.")
        ...
```

Or, to be a bit more lenient and pythonic:

```
class Quad(object):

    def __init__(sideAB, sideDA, angle):
        self.sideAB = float(sideAB)
        ...
```

Which will raise a `ValueError` for you if it can't make a `float`, and handle e.g. `q = Quad("1", "2", "3")` without a fuss.

Comment: Thanks, under specifications (this is part of a project) I have a __validate function so could I do something with the isinstance checking on all the parameters and if they all are valid then a valid attribute set to true? If this wasn't a project I could be a lot more flexible with my code but even if the parameter is entered as a string but would be valid like sideAB = "10" I am supposed to set that as invalid.